# PySpark: Convert a pair RDD back to a regular RDD

Tags: pyspark, rdd, keyvaluepair

Is there any way I can convert a pair RDD back to a regular RDD?

Suppose I get a local csv file, and I first load it as a regular rdd

```
rdd = sc.textFile("$path/$csv")
```

Then I create a pair rdd (i.e. key is the string before "," and value is the string after ",")

```
pairRDD = rdd.map(lambda x : (x.split(",")[0], x.split(",")[1]))
```

I store the pairRDD by using the saveAsTextFile()

```
pairRDD.saveAsTextFile("$savePath")
```

However, as investigated, the stored file will contain some necessary characters, such as "u'", "(" and ")" (as pyspark simply calls toString(), to store key-value pairs)
I was wondering if I can convert back to a regular rdd, so that the saved file wont contain "u'" or "(" and ")"?
Or any other storage methods I can use to get rid of the unnecessary characters ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters are the Python representation of your data as string (tuples and Unicode strings). You should convert your data to text (i.e. a single string per record) since you use `saveAsTextFile`. You can use map to convert the key/value tuple into a single value again, e.g.:

```
pairRDD.map(lambda (k,v): "Value %s for key %s" % (v,k)).saveAsTextFile(savePath)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Really understand the structure well from your explanation. I have tried another way like: pairRDD.map(lambda (x,y): (x+","+y)).saveAsTextFile($savePath). This stores a pair rdd as a csv file (sort of converting it back to a regular rdd).

Comment: hello how to do that with java ?