# Transform Java-Pair-Rdd to Rdd

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, key-value, java-pair-rdd

I need to transform my Java-pair-rdd to a csv :

so i m thinking to transform it to rdd, to solve my problem.

what i want is to have my rdd transformed
from :

```
Key   Value
Jack  [a,b,c]
```

to :

```
Key  value
Jack  a
Jack  b
Jack  c
```

i see that it is possible in that [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504400/load-spark-rdd-to-neo4j-in-python?noredirect=1#comment89507177_39504400) and in this issue([PySpark: Convert a pair RDD back to a regular RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971315/pyspark-convert-a-pair-rdd-back-to-a-regular-rdd/32975221#comment89543754_32975221))
so  i am asking how to do that in java?

## Update of question

The Type of my *JavaPairRdd* is of Type :

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String,String>, Iterable<Tuple1<String>>>
```

and this is the form of row that contain :

```
((dr5rvey,dr5ruku),[(2,01/09/2013 00:09,01/09/2013 00:27,N,1,-73.9287262,40.75831223,-73.98726654,40.76442719,2,3.96,16,0.5,0.5,4.25,0,,21.25,1,)])
```

the **key** here is : `(dr5rvey,dr5ruku)` and the **value** is `[(2,01/09/2013 00:09,01/09/2013 00:27,N,1,-73.9287262,40.75831223,-73.98726654,40.76442719,2,3.96,16,0.5,0.5,4.25,0,,21.25,1,)]`

my original *JavaRdd* was of type:

```
JavaRDD<String>
```

Comment: This is exactly the same question as you [asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246926/write-javapairrdd-to-csv). If you have more info then update that question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that the keys should be kept, you may use flatMapValues function :

> Pass each value in the key-value pair RDD through a flatMap function without changing the keys; ...

```
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String,String>, Iterable<Tuple1<String>>> input = ...;
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple1<String>> output1 = input.flatMapValues(iter -> iter);
JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, String> output2 = output1.mapValues(t1 -> t1._1());
```

Comment: thanks, but even the keys shouldn't have parantheses =>**i need a csv in the end**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to use the function flat map, it enables you to create multiple rows from a single key, example in scala(just the idea youll need to change for your use case):

```
rdd.flatMap(arg0 => {
        var list = List[Row]()
        list = arg0._2.split(",")
        list
    })
```

Its a super simplified example but you should get the gist.

for rdd:

```
key      val
mykey   "a,b,c'
```

the returned rdd will be:

```
key      val
mykey   "a"
mykey   "b"
mykey   "c"
```

Comment: arg0 is the key  here ?

Comment: fixed the code arg0 is a tuple arg0._1 is the key arg0._2 is the val

Answer (score 0):

The type of your `RDD` is `RDD[(String, Array[String])]` if I am getting this right. So you can just apply flatMap on this RDD.

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, Array[String])] = ???
val newRDD = rdd.flatMap{case (key, array) => array.map(value => (key, value))}
```

`newRDD` will be of type `RDD[(String, String)]`